# xarray change the name of coordinates in dataarray

Tags: python, python-xarray

I feel like i missed something important because the answer to my question seems like it would be easy to find.

Showing a MEW: Let's say i have an xarray,

```
da = xr.DataArray(
    data=np.ones((10,10,2)),
    dims=['x', 'y', 'orientation'],
    coords={
        "orientation": [1, 2] 
    }
)
```

It has coordinates `1` and `2` for the dimension `orientation`. How would i change the coordinates from `1` to `one` and `2` to `two`?

The [rename](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/latest/generated/xarray.DataArray.rename.html) method sounds like it can help, and i tried things like

```
da.rename(orientation={1:'one', 2: 'two'})
```

or

```
da.rename({1:'one', 2: 'two'})
```

to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xarray's [rename](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/latest/generated/xarray.DataArray.rename.html) method is used to rename keys in the data object (e.g. coordinate names). If you want to replace the values in a coordinate itself, you can simply set those directly:

```py
da['orientation'] = ['one', 'two']
# or using assing_coords
da = da.assign_coords({'orientation': ['one', 'two']})
```